# How to play Dolby TrueHD 7.1 ATMOS files?

Tags: codecs

I have a video file with the audio codec "Dolby TrueHD 7.1 ATMOS" but the audio won't come out at all. I've tried vlc, avplay and a bunch of other players. I even updated vlc to 2.2 and libav-tools to 11

How do I play such a file? **Preferably in VLC!!!**

*You can get a sample file from [here](http://thedigitaltheater.com/index.php/dolby-trailers/). Make sure you download a file with "Dolby TrueHD 7.1 ATMOS" audio. The "Conductor " file is 40MB*

Comment: Do you have the equipment necessary to play it? See http://www.engadget.com/2008/01/22/how-to-actually-use-dolby-truehd-and-dts-hd/ for clarification. If you are downmixing it anyway to use fewer speakers you aren't actually hearing the content in question.

Comment: @ElderGeek yes I'm down-mixing it to 4 channels (+subwoofer) .. I know I'm not getting the best out of it but that doesn't mean I should watch the video without sound :P and btw I could get it to work (see sol. below) and the audio quality is much **much** better than files with 4 channel audio

Comment: Related: http://www.audioholics.com/audio-technologies/5-reasons-dolby-atmos-is-doa

Comment: I just installed kodi for Macos. It plays the conductor file fine to my very recent (summer 2016) Onkyo TX-RZ810 via HDMI from my macbook.
The amp says its Dolby 7:1, but doesn't seem to recognize that it's Atmos.
My understanding is that Atmos has the to ceiling speakers (bouncing off ceiling in my case with Onkyo SKS-HT5BB(B) speakers) whereas 7.1 has extra surround speakers.
So it's great to finally get 8 channels working but disappointed that I don't get the vertical volume effect from the ceiling yet. Still searching ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## VLC

The current stable release of VLC (2.2.4) does not support Dolby Atmos 7.1 sound.

The current nightly build of version 3 does support Dolby Atmos.
The fix was [committed on February 2nd, 2017](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=commit;h=947362db184089cb45a015b4e5cada10a58b1c89).
There is a [closed ticket](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/15478) on this issue.

## mplayer

mplayer supports Dolby Atmos TrueHD 7.1 as of sometime before 2017.

I have not been able to find exactly when this was fixed in mplayer.
It seems it was fixed in ffmpeg, which mplayer uses, [back in 2015](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=36bf549b2706bd10014556a84a33ed6daf5d5373).

See http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3960 for more history.

## Kodi

Kodi uses **mplayer** for video playback and therefore will support TrueHD audio as long as the underlying **mplayer** version does.

Comment: Cool so vlc has recently added support to it. I've just tried it and apparently there's a issue, I think I can report it sometime. thx

Comment: Does ubuntu support Dolby Atmos ?

Answer (score 1):

well I just tried `kodi` and it played the audio just fine! *The user interface is INCREDIBLE!!!!!!*

To install kodi:

make sure you have this installed:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

then you can use this repository and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

...still I'd want VLC to play it. Anyone knows where to get the missing (whatever) codec for VLC?